# @Published not updating view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using a barcode scanner in my app, and to show each product on a view when it's barcode is scanned.

I have a sheet that show's details of the product and I want it to reload when ScannedCode is updated.

For each class that uses the barcode, I declare it like:

```
    @ObservedObject var scannedCode: ScannedCode
```

But when I change the value, the views don't update.

I declare ScannedCode in my contentView:

```
class ScannedCode: ObservableObject {
    @Published var barcode = ""
}
class dbProduct: ObservableObject {
    @Published var result = Result()
}

    struct ContentView: View {
        let scannedCode = ScannedCode()
        let product = dbProduct()
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                ScannerView(scannedCode: scannedCode) //Starts the scanner
                FoundItemSheet(scannedCode: scannedCode, product: product)
            }
        }
    }
```

When the scanner finds a product, it updates the barcode in it's Coordinator:

```
 class Coordinator: BarcodeScannerCodeDelegate, BarcodeScannerErrorDelegate {
        @ObservedObject var scannedCode: ScannedCode
        
    private var scannerView: ScannerView
        init(_ scannerView: ScannerView, barcode: ScannedCode) {
            self.scannerView = scannerView
            self.scannedCode = barcode
        }
        
        func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didCaptureCode code: String, type: String) {
            self.scannedCode.barcode = code //Updates the barcode here
            controller.resetWithError(message: "Error message")
        }

        func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didReceiveError error: Error) {
          print(error)
        }
    }
```

FoundItemSheet calls BottomSheetView, which displays the product. productDataView calculates which data to be shown on BottomSheetView as its content().

When the body is loaded for BottomSheetView() I call the API and store the data into an @ObservedObject so productDataView can access it.

```
.onAppear{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let hashedValue = scannedCode.barcode.hashedValue("Ls75O8z1q9Ep9Kz0")
            self.loadData(url: *API Call with barcode*) {
//...Load data converts from JSON and stores the product
```

This is where I suspect it could be going wrong, as the barcode that's changed in the scanner Coordinator isn't being updated here.

EDIT:

**ScannerView**

```
extension UINavigationController {
   open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
   }
}

struct ScannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var scannedCode: ScannedCode

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, barcode: scannedCode)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScannerView>) -> BarcodeScannerViewController {
        return createAndConfigureScanner(context: context)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: BarcodeScannerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScannerView>) {
            uiViewController.reset(animated: false)
      }

     private func createAndConfigureScanner(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScannerView>) -> BarcodeScannerViewController {
        let barcodeVC = BarcodeScannerViewController()
        barcodeVC.codeDelegate = context.coordinator
        barcodeVC.errorDelegate = context.coordinator
        return barcodeVC
    }
}
```

Comment: Your mistake here is using `onAppear`. It doesn't add any observers, it's executed once the view appears. You also shouldn't put the responsibility on the view to observe and _then_ load data. All of this can be done in the (view)model. The view should only be responsible for presenting data.

Comment: You didn't post the code for `ScannerView` (would be helpful).But maybe you could try changing `let scannedCode = ScannedCode()` to `@ObservedObject var scannedCode: ScannedCode`. Also, if you drop a breakpoint in `didCaptureCode` of the coordinator, is it ever called?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I see. That makes sense. Should I put the content's in .onAppear into a function instead? Something like loadAPIData()?

Comment: @Samuel-IH I'll add ScannerView now, and I'll change those parts you suggested.

Comment: @Toby the parts I suggested actually may be incorrect, Claus has a very good point. It would be helpful to have the ScannerView code though.